# DEP (Data Execution Prevention) violation on executable address?

Tags: debugging, windbg

My app crashed at startup in an MSHTML worker thread. The EXCEPTION_RECORD gives:

```
0:066> .exr 0e11f668 
ExceptionAddress: 732019ab (rtutils!AcquireWriteLock+0x00000010)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000008
   Parameter[1]: 732019ab
Attempt to execute non-executable address 732019ab
```

But `!address` shows that the address 732019ab is indeed executable:

```
0:066> !address 732019ab
Usage:                  Image
Base Address:           73201000
End Address:            7320a000
Region Size:            00009000
State:                  00001000    MEM_COMMIT
Protect:                00000020    PAGE_EXECUTE_READ
Type:                   01000000    MEM_IMAGE
Allocation Base:        73200000
Allocation Protect:     00000080    PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY
Image Path:             C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rtutils.dll
Module Name:            rtutils
Loaded Image Name:      rtutils.dll
Mapped Image Name:      
More info:              lmv m rtutils
More info:              !lmi rtutils
More info:              ln 0x732019ab
More info:              !dh 0x73200000
```

The instruction at 732019ab is:

```
0:066> u 732019ab l1
rtutils!AcquireWriteLock+0x10:
732019ab 8d4618          lea     eax,[esi+18h]
```

Why is a DEP violation being reported at an address whose page is marked as PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, that seems pretty impossible. I don't have an answer, but the list of possibilities is too long for a comment.

If I were to guess, I'd say something is playing with the protection flags on that page, but putting it back to `PAGE_EXECUTE_READ` after (or while) the exception is being raised. Start by seeing if your code (or any libraries you use) plays with [`VirtualProtect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If that doesn't reveal anything, we can move onto some other possibilities:

1. **Malware**

   Some malware likes to play with hooking/hotpatching and has been known to cause similar problems.
2. **Faulty Antivirus**

   Antivirus applications employ a lot of the same tricks as malware. If issues stop after disabling it, you've found your culprit and can look at updating/replacing it.
3. **A Bad Kernel Driver**

   In kernel mode, you can achieve the impossible accidentally, but never on purpose. :)
4. **A Faulty CPU**

   An overclocked or poorly cooled CPU can cause many unpredictable things to happen. Not likely, but possible.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I'll keep those possibilities in mind. Strangely enough, after being able to repro the problem 2 times (both violations in rtutils.dll but at different offsets) it stopped happening.